# RealTime communication Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, request, client

assuming you have a server and a client, the server is able to perform operations, the client is always waiting for the server to perform operations. The client knows the address of the server, the server does not. How can the client always keep in touch with the server in order to be informed whenever the server performs operations?

Comment: What you search for is called [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: I have documented myself on the webSockets, but communication in this area is between the client's browser and the server, I would like to implement direct communication, door to door, where is the client that initiates communication with the server

Comment: I don't understand you: a `WebSocket` is initiated **by the client**, and once initiated both sides are able to send data to each other.

Comment: Exactly, and this is done via a web page chat, I would rather do it without a web page

Comment: There are WebSocket clients for non browser envs, like [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) for node.js

Comment: is what I was looking for, thanks a lot!